# Am I not getting the || operator when using != in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I have the following code that tries to convert a time string, e.g. "9:45" or simply "9" into seconds, do some calculations, and then return in in proper HH:MM format again. While I succeed to accomplish the format e.g. "9:45", I can't seem figure out how to do it when it's simply "9". It comes down to the if statement using || and != operators, but I can't get to to work and my output is `NaN:NaN`

Here is my code:

```
    var the_time = "10";
    var the_travel_time = 643 // This is already given in seconds

    var hms = the_time;   // your input string

    if (hms != "11" || hms != "10" || hms != "9"|| hms != "8") {

    var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

    // minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
    var the_time_inSeconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]*60);

    } else {
    var the_time_inSeconds = parseInt(hms)
    var the_time_inSeconds = hms * 60 * 60;
    }

    //the following code calculates the leave time
    //the_travel_time is taken from google's api call

    var the_leave_time = the_time_inSeconds - the_travel_time;

    var leave_hours = Math.floor(the_leave_time / 60 / 60);

    var leave_minutes = Math.floor(the_leave_time / 60) - (leave_hours * 60);

var the_leave_format = leave_hours + ':' + leave_minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

Comment: "If hms is not equal to 11 or hms is not equal to 10 ..." — do you see the flaw in that logic? If it **is** equal to 11, then it is also **not equal** to 10, etc.

Comment: Are u sure  to use || because it always enter if condtition. Because  hms can't be 4 different value at the same time. U may want && instead of ||

Comment: Also if `hms` is a string like "9:30" then it will never be equal to those simple numeric strings anyway.

Comment: And you only need to declare a given variable once.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you can simplify your code by just always splitting. `"10".split(':')` gives `[10]`. Thus you can do `(+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + ( (+a[1] || 0) *60);`. The inline or `(+a[1] || 0)` tells it to use 0 if `a[1]` is undefined.

Comment: Oh my. I see now. The code compiles if I use the && operator, so now I am able to define both e.g. "9:30" or "9 "etc.

Comment: Also in your `else` part you converted to `hms` to integer but not used. And assigning value to same variable multiple time. 

So when hms (string) multiplied by 60 * 60 it will give you **NaN**

Answer (score 0):

you are mishandling your logic in if condition:

```
if(hms != "11" || hms != "10" || hms != "9"|| hms != "8") {
    // with this logic all the flow passes through here 
else {
    // never flows around here
}
```

one option is to check the length of your string:

```
if( has.length > 1 ) {
    hms.split(':')
    // ...
} else {
   // ...
}
```

I recommend you read this [Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)